# Get an event triggered when text change unity?

Tags: android, textarea, unity-game-engine

Here the Text Area is constantly changing in terms of number and I want to trigger an event when the Text Area gets a particular number example I have tried this -

```
 public void myfunction45(Canvas Panel)
{
    if (Indicator = 45) {     
    Panel.enabled = false;.
    }
} //(indicator- www.progress).
```

But it does not work(it does not read it nothing happens). how do I match the condition as the number is to be specific. please give an example for explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That if statement would cause you problems.

You would want:

```
if(Indicator == 5)
```

instead. At the moment you're assigning the value without checking it, this would cause a compiler error. If it's just a typo, then update your answer, slightly confusing otherwise.

With regards to checking the text value. You'd have to grab the text value, for that you need a reference to the Text area. This approach assumes that the text area has it's value set by a user. Currently you're not grabbing any text values to compare, as a result, the if statement won't know what to compare.

Here's one approach:

```
public void myfunction5(Canvas Panel)
{
    float result;

    string textValue = yourTextArea.text;

    if(Single.TryParse(textValue, out result))
    {
        if(result == Indicator)
        {
             Panel.enabled = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

You use TryParse to avoid any potential exceptions that would be thrown if the user entered something that wasn't a number. This method will take the value from your text area, how you get your text area is up to you, and try to parse the text value into a float. The method will return true if the parse was a success, false otherwise.

Here's the reference for the TryParse stuff:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx

If you wanted to parse it to an int, then you'd be using the Int32's version of TryParse, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

I'd also recommend having a peak at the Input Field documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html

You can subscribe your method to the Input-fields On Value Changed event, your function will need to tweaked slightly though:

```
public void myfunction5(string text)
{
    float result;

    if(Single.TryParse(text, out result))
    {
        if(result == Indicator)
        {
             CachedPanel.enabled = false;
        }
    }  
}
```

Don't forget to store a reference to the panel you want to disable.

Hopefully this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

`Panel` is already a Canvas type, it doesn't make any sense to `GetComponent<Canvas>` on the same type.

Try using `Panel.enabled = false;`.

For the rest, we don't know how you get the `Indicator` reference, or how you built the UI hierarchy, so we can't assess if the problem is there.

Edit: I could I miss the single `=` baffles me lol. I should avoid answering questions when I'm tired.

Comment: We still don't know what's happening outside this method, please provide the whole script. Have you tried putting a `Debug.Log` inside the if to check if it's never met or if there's a problem with disabling the Canvas component? Are you trying to disable the component or the object? Because for the latter you need to use `Panel.SetActive(false);`

Comment: i was trying to disable the component of canvas not the object itself but it works both ways and I am downloading file and at its full download i wanted to show another canvas showing the download complete text n image. here is the code for the download process -

Comment: WWW www = new WWW (requestURL);
  while (!www.isDone) {
   if (isInQueue (requestURL)) {
    Debug.Log("Progress : " + www.progress);
    if (requestURLInEditor == requestURL) {
     currentProgressInEditor = www.progress;
     if (currentProgressInEditor > 0.995) {
      currentProgressInEditor = 1.0f;
     }
    }